# Scheduling Problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization, operations-research

My boss asked me to come up with a presentation that recommends how many hires she would need to support our tests. I have data that shows the number of tests per day. Assuming one worker per test, how could I recommend the minimum number of workers needed to ensure we have enough for a given day with X probability that the number of tests wont go over the number of employees? I remember doing problems like this in my Linear optimization class, but I cannot for the life of me remember what the technique or class of problems was called.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may have other business-related constraints that you know better. So, I just give you two suggestions about the type of problems you can look into:
1) [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)  2) [Nurse Scheduling Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurse_scheduling_problem)